# Can't show modal with errors if submit isn't successful [Devise]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, registration

My problem is to show modal with errors if submit is not successful.

I should try AJAX or it can be done without it?

I should override registration controller?

Comment: what have you tried so far? Take a look here: [Ruby on Rails Tutorial: Learn Rails by Example](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec:signup_error_messages)

Comment: It is awesome tutorial, but for static pages.I didn't mention in comment, that I'm using Devise. So I need to override it, yes ?
Or just use THESE user controllers ?

Comment: actually this tutorial is not only for static pages and the validations messages is for dynamic resources.... I don't use Devise, but I will reply this answer with my approach..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for example:

model User with some validations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name,        :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false },
                          :presence => true
  validates :email,       :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false },
                          :presence => true,
  ...
end
```

I use a shared partial to display the errors that prevent the data in a form to be saved:

_error_messages.html.erb

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
  <h3><%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>
    prohibited this <%= object.class.to_s.underscore.humanize.downcase %>
    from being saved:</h3>
  <p>There were problems with the following fields:</p>
  <ul>
  <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In the form to create or edit a new user:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
...
```

Comment: Ok,thanks.  will try to do that. It is so hard to overide some features in Devise, so I maybe reject it too)

Comment: I have one more question: how I can call modal from UsersControllers?

Comment: sorry, but I didn't understand what you mean by "call modal". However I have edited my answer to include the controller. I hope it helps... any doubt please let me know.

Comment: I mean bootstrap modal. Here is link - > http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

Comment: well, I don't use the bootstrap modal to display messages... in rails I use the flash, which is part of Rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash